# How many pages did Henry read in the first day? (Can you show a method?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Henry reads a book with $450$ pages. He reads $2$ pages more than last day he reads. If he finished reading this book in $18$ days, how many pages did Henry read in the first day?

This book has $450$ pages, and he finished reading this book in $18$ days.

Let amount of pages be $x$

$x+2, x+4, x+6, x+8.... $

In 18th day we have

$x+20$

Hence we get

$x+20 = 420$

$x = 21$

Why isn't it correct answer or what am I missing?

Comment: If he reads $x$ days on day one, and he reads $x+2$ pages on day two, then combined over the first two days he read a total of $2x+2$ pages.  Similarly he will have read $3x+6$ pages total by the third day, etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz Then we have $18x +36 = 420$, right?

Comment: Why "$+36$" ?  Why "$=420$"?  There are $450$ pages in the book total, not $420$.  The number of pages read on the $n$'th day alone is $x+2n-2$.  The *total* number of pages read by the $n$'th day would be $x+(x+2)+(x+4)+(x+6)+\dots+(x+2n-2)$, which simplifies nicely if you know about triangular numbers or solving recurrence relations and it does not simplify as $18x+36$.

Comment: For the $18$'th day specifically, $x+(x+2)+(x+4)+(x+6)+\dots+(x+34)=18x+(2+4+6+8+\dots+34)$

Answer (score 3):

Let's say Henry reads x number of pages on the first day.
Since every day he reads two pages more than the previous day, he must read $x+2$ on the second day.
$x+4$ on third day and so on. There is a pattern there.
On every nth day he reads $ x + 2(n-1) $ pages.
 On the 18th day he must read $ x + 2(18-1) $ pages.

We are given the book has $450$ pages, that means the sum of all the pages he read every day is equal to $ 450$
$$ x + (x + 2) + (x+4) + ... (x + 34) = 450 $$
$$ 18x + 2 + 4 + 6 ... + 34 = 450 $$
$$ 18x + 2(1+2+3 ... + 17) = 450 $$
$$ 18x + 2\frac{17*18}{2} = 450 $$
$$ 18x + 306 = 450 $$
$$ 18x = 144 $$
$$ x = 8 $$

So Henry read 8 pages on the first day.